# Allow guest to update custom post met using ajax

Tags: ajax, post-meta

I have a simple click counter that works using ajax, only problem is that if you're not logged in you can't update the counter meta box of the post.

In my case the post it's an ad that when clicked triggers the ajax function.

Is it possible to allow guest to update post meta on the front end using ajax?

UPDATE:

This is the jQuery script:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('.ad.<?php echo $post->ID; ?>').click(function() { 
        jQuery('#<?php echo $post->ID; ?>').submit();
    });
    jQuery('#<?php echo $post->ID; ?>').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: "action=adClickCounter&id="+<?php echo $post->ID?>,  
            success: function() {
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
                }, 50);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my click counter function:

```
function adClickCounter_ajax() {

$post_id = $_POST['id'];
$adClickCount = get_post_meta($post_id, '_adClickCount', true);
$adClickCount = $adClickCount + 1;
update_post_meta($post_id,'_adClickCount',$adClickCount);
die($adClickCount);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_adClickCounter', 'adClickCounter_ajax');
```

Comment: What does your server side code look?

Comment: Please share your code logic that what you are trying and what is going wrong.

Comment: Just update my entry. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There are two hooks for adding AJAX handlers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)), you're missing the one for non-logged in visitors. You need:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_adClickCounter', 'adClickCounter_ajax' );
```

... in addition to the `add_action` call you currently have. Note the extra `nopriv_` in the tag.

Comment: Works like a charm. I will check all the codex documentation about `wp_ajax`, I spend many minutes looking for something like this. Guess didn't type the right question in google. Thanks.